# Would you be interested in a SE site for Greek or Hebrew?

Tags: discussion

Our [FAQ](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/faq) states:

> Questions that do not arise from a Biblical text are generally off-topic, even if they are about:
>
> ...
>
> - the Greek and Hebrew languages

What that means is that you can't really ask about Greek or Hebrew language and usage unless you can find a way to connect it to a Biblical text.  You'll notice that we have links to other SE sites if you happen to be interested in [Judaism](http://judaism.stackexchange.com), [Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com), or [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com).  But we don't yet have an alternative for Greek and Hebrew.  (We also don't link to the [History](http://history.stackexchange.com) site for some reason, but that's a separate issue.)

As it turns out, there are proposals for both Greek and Hebrew:

- [Hebrew Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage)

  Biblical Hebrew seems very much on topic on this proposal.  It needs more questions and more votes on the existing questions in order to move onto the commitment stage.
- [Greek Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36736/greek-language-usage)

  Unfortunately, Koine Greek (and other ancient dialects) seem to be [off-topic](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/modern-greek-only-or-ancient-greek-too) under the current proposal.  But there's still time to rally support around a broader scope.  ([Classical Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38759/classical-languages) might be an alternative, but it's not really getting much traction and I don't think the topic has been settled yet.)  Since the proposer of the site has specifically [contacted us](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6735155#6735155) to solicit "good questions about the language (Modern, Medieval/Byzantine, Koine, Ancient, Proto-Greek)" I encourage you to follow the proposal and ask any questions you might have.  Also, upvote questions you'd like to see on a Greek Language & Usage site.

(While I'm at it, I'd like to plug a proposal *I'm* most interested in: [E-books and E-book Readers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/e-books-and-e-book-readers).  Since I got a Kindle Touch 11 months ago, I've practically stopped reading traditional books and it's revolutionized my reading habit.  Having access to digitized books, especially old and obscure books my library doesn't carry, has helped me learn about the Biblical texts.)

I've often said that Stack Exchange (and the internet itself) is *not a zero-sum game*!  We won't lose out if people have access to better places to ask questions about Greek and Hebrew.  We will actually benefit from an increased network effect as more related sites establish healthy communities.

[Feel free to answer this question with suggestions of other related projects (Stack Exchange related or not) that you feel will be of interest to the Biblical Hermeneutics community.]

Comment: First, thank you for plugging my proposal. The proposed questions (so far) are overwhelmingly about Modern Greek, but I don't see any reason to not welcome questions about Koine and let the followers of the proposal shape it through their votes.

Answer (score 3):

What about one for "biblical languages"

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in one for Hebrew, Greek, and Latin. Maybe even Aramaic, but I guess that is not as popular.